# Altering default open all files in folder option

Tags: vba, excel

Excel has an option within `Excel/File/Options/Advanced` which allows a user to have files within a folder open on startup. This is located under the general tab in Advanced which is called "*At startup, open all files in:*".

- Could this potentially be manipulated through VBA?

I've done some research but found nothing on this topic. I'd like to create a simple sub that sets this to `C:\test`

```
Sub SetFolder()

'Do something to set option to ("C:\test")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you're after is `Application.AltStartupPath`

```
Sub SetFolder()
    Application.AltStartupPath = "C:\test\"
End Sub
```